# Pandas file reader error FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3]

Tags: pandas

I have the following

```
import os
import pandas as pd 
path = 'C:/PanelComplete/FileForPeter/'
for folder in os.listdir(path):
for file in os.listdir(folder):
    df = pd.read_csv(path+folder+'/'+file,engine='python')
    df1 = df.groupby('codprg').size().reset_index(name='counts')
    df1.to_csv(spath1+folder+'.csv', index=False,encoding='utf-8')
```

it causes the following problem `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '20180101'`
even the path is right as in the following snipping

[image]

This case is asked rapidly but my case is different

Comment: I believe in the second `for` you should pass `path+folder` not only `folder`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Celius Stingher it works now

Comment: Made it an answer so it's official :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the second `for` you are placing the `folder` name only instead of the full path (`path+folder`), hence you are not correctly addressing your desired directory. This should work:

```
import os
import pandas as pd 
path = 'C:/PanelComplete/FileForPeter/'
for folder in os.listdir(path):
for file in os.listdir(path+folder):
    df = pd.read_csv(path+folder+'/'+file,engine='python')
    df1 = df.groupby('codprg').size().reset_index(name='counts')
    df1.to_csv(spath1+folder+'.csv', index=False,encoding='utf-8')
```